# SQL dump of users tables Gmed emr

Tags: sql-server

I am working for a company that uses Gmed EMR. Gmed lacks some features that my client requires and I have had to build an external secure web based application to fill in. Gmed runs on Microsoft SQL server. I have access to the server, but I've never used Microsoft SQL server before. How can I safety SQL dump the users tables? Should I even try this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a dump, do the following (OTTOMH):

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio
2. Right click on your database
3. On the menu go to TASKS and then GENERATE SCRIPTS then click NEXT
4. Choose "Specific Objects"
5. Choose the tables that you want
6. In the options make sure you choose the option for SCRIPT DATA
7. Choose to put it into a script or a window and click FINISH

This will give you a script to create the table, as well as the INSERT statements for data.

If you want just the data dump, you can right click a database and choose to EXPORT data.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the format you want them in.  It's pretty easy to export to a text file.  Open SQL Server Management Studio (the GUI), right-click the database you want to export from, then click `Export Data`.  It's a straightforward wizard that lets you select what tables or other objects you want to export, and in what format or to what file.